# Birthday for coming week

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with column in GBQ birthdate.
I want to get all user which have birthday coming following 7 days.

I have tried below code but it is giving error as i know we cannot compare date Int64 ,month int64 with birthday Date.

```
select
  DISTINCT(`email_contacts`.`id`) AS contactId,
   `email_contacts`.`gender`
from
  `xxxx`.`abc`.`customer` as `users`
where
     `email_contacts`.`birthday` 
      Between   
      EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE '2013-12-25') 
      and 
      EXTRACT(Month FROM DATE '2000-12-25')
```

Comment: your `where` clause is essentially evaluating to `where birthday between 25 and 12`

Comment: I have resolved issue: I am passing date range with month and days SELECT DISTINCT(`email_contacts`.`id`) AS contactId, `email_contacts`.`gender` FROM `xxxx`.`abc`.`customer` as `users` where FORMAT_DATE("%m-%d", birthday) in (07-23', '07-24', '07-25', '07-26', '07-27')

Comment: Consider looking at BigMoney's answer below.  The `BETWEEN` will make your code easier to maintain.  If you need to change your window from 7 to 14 days (for example), you would only need to change 1 item in your `BETWEEN` clause, rather than add 7 more items to your 'IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(`email_contacts`.`id`) AS contactId, `email_contacts`.`gender`
FROM `xxxx`.`abc`.`customer` as `users`
WHERE birthday
  BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```